# Visual Studio / RestSharp - Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret (CS0118)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, restsharp

I have only been coding for about two years now (off and on) but I'm well acquainted with this cryptic error across multiple versions of VS.  I know this issue isn't related to just RestSharp.

This 'caret error' has been the bane of my VS experience so that is why I'm here.

**Environment:**

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.1
RestClient v4.0.30319
Windows 10 Professional

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm following the very simple directions on the RestClient [site](https://restsharp.dev/getting-started/getting-started.html).  I have installed RestClient, added references but when I try to get started I get that dreaded caret error.

None of this is my code aside from the reference to RestClient, which may or may not be appropriate (I don't know).

**[Screen Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO1hj.png)**

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using RestClient;

namespace newDawn2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com/1.1");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");

            var request = new RestRequest("statuses/home_timeline.json", DataFormat.Json);

            var response = client.Get(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You have RestClient declared as a namespace in a using statement and then try and instantiate it, which is what the error is saying.   Looking at the sample you linked, you need to remove the RestClient using statement.  It's uncommon and confusing for a class to share a name with part of it's namespace.

Comment: As @Adam mentioned and going in the same direction as him, you should avoid having a *Namespace* called exactly as the *Type*. In the example provided RestSharp site there is no *using RestClient;*. In case you have created your custom Type for whatever reason try to avoid calling the *type* exactly in the same way.
For instance: NameSpace: MyDomian.MyCustomRestClient.

Comment: Thank you, but I only added that statement after encountering this error (desperation).  I have now removed the RestClient declaration in namespace, no effect.    snip: https://i.imgur.com/5FauKbJ.png

Comment: What happens when you remove the RestSharp using statements and fully declare the client: RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.twitter.com/1.1");

Comment: Good things happened!  https://i.imgur.com/CMawNJt.png    However in order to make the rest of the code work (RestRequest), I had to add using RestSharp back in: https://i.imgur.com/10mjKy6.png  But thank you!  I'm trying to find out how I upvote posts here.

Answer (score 1):

```
using RestClient;
```

Here you are declaring that you are using the namespace RestClient, not the object.

```
var client = new RestClient(...
```

The error is raised here because you are trying to create an instance of the namespace you just declared you were using.

It's uncommon and confusing for an object to share a name with part of its namespace, so you should generally not expect to see a using statement with the same name you use to create an object.
Namespaces are used to separate, organize classes and limit what classes are loaded at compile time.
Classes of the same name can exist in different namespaces.
You could create your own class named RestClient and use it in this project as well(maybe for testing) as long as they existed in different namespaces.  The full declaration of the class you are using now is RestSharp.RestClient.  You could create a class with the full declaration Facundo.Test.RestClient and use them both in the same project.  However, in this case, you could not use using statements and everytime you wanted to instantiate one or the other you would need to fully declare the namespace

```
RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient(...);
```

or

```
Facundo.Test.RestClient testClient = new Facundo.Test.RestClient(...);
```

I would not recommend naming them the same in practice, just trying to illustrate namespaces.